# Is there an anonymous proxy application for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, proxy

I've been digging around to find a proxy application something like `proxifier` in windows but cannot find any thing! and then tried to configure the system wide proxy setting in network section of Ubuntu’s system setting and I configure the proxy setting but it seems it does not apply anything...

here is my questions :

Is there any proxy application to use like `proxifier` in windows!?

If there is no proxy application how can I configure system's proxy setting manually!?

thanks in advance

Comment: maybe `anon-proxy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed someone commented on this thread, though this is an old question, but thought maybe it's good to share my accomplishments.

After sometime i found [kerio](http://www.kerio.com/) application and i have been using this application for quite sometime, and **it is awesome**!! It does NOT lower down your connection speed and in general it is just perfect, It's client is free and i used it in both windows and linux(ubuntu) and it is just perfect.

By it self it does not provide vpn account free, after you setup the `kerio` you need to buy a `kerio vpn` account, can be found easily on internet. then if your vpn account provider has good servers, you would be 100% happy with results.

[image]
You can find setup instruction [here](http://download.kerio.com/dwn/control/control-8.2.2-1619/kerio-control-vpnclient-8.2.2-1619-linux.deb.readme).

I hope that help.

Answer (score 4):

"Proxifier" for Windows seems like an anonymous proxy/VPN-type-thing.

On Ubuntu then, you want [Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29).

Get the Tor Bundle at https://www.torproject.org/download/download

Answer (score 1):

Try ProxyChains.  It powers any TCP connection to follow through proxy (or proxy chain). It is a kind of proxifier.  To install it, first [Download it](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proxychains/proxychains_3.1-3_all.deb), and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens: Navigate to the folder where the file downloaded,

```
cd download loacation

sudo dpkg -i proxychains_3.1-3_all.deb
```

or you can get it from USC

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use zenmate it's a google chrome extension

Comment: Why? How does this serve any purpose?